# how to smoothly fold a curved plane over a curved edge?

Tags: modeling, mesh, geometry

[image]

Hi guys, I'm very new to Blender and I'm trying to model this little seat I made (just a rough prototype so pls ignore how scrappy it looks haha) but I just can't figure out how to fold the edges of the back to the curve of the seat - if I even attempt it, the mesh gets super messed up...

As shown, the top part of the back is meant to be folded down and the bottom part is meant to be folded up to the underside of the seat, so the whole thing looks like a bow shape (if you get what I mean).

To make the back so far I’ve just taken the edge loop of the seat shape and extruded the points to make a plane and then used solidify - if i subdivide and add loads of mesh points I'm scared it'll get even harder to figure out the right vertices to select to fold it up/down?

Maybe I've gone about this wrong in the first place, I feel like there's a more straightforward (or at least more accurate) way to do this...can anyone please help? I would really appreciate it in as much detail as you can offer, thank you so much!!

Comment: I also think that duplicating an edge loop of the seat and extruding it up is the way to go , why are you not satisfied with what it gives?

Comment: Do not subdivide, use a Subdivision Surface modifier instead, if you need to apply the modifier for some reason (like you need to 3D print), always keep the original in a collection

Comment: Just to be absolutely clear.. the seat can be modelled as shown without any folding at all. Is it the folding, in particular, you want to investigate, say, to simulate real-life upholstery?